# Need a PCI sniffer

Tags: pci, sniffer

I'd like to look at PCI transmission but I can't find any tool for it. Does anyone know how to sniff data exchanged with PCI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RWEverthing](http://jacky5488.myweb.hinet.net/) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be very good tool.

Comment: @Marcin Zet: Just beware it can make your system very unstable, or make it BSOD  :)